# Add Isolated Storage Files into Setup Project

Tags: installation, windows-installer, setup-project, isolatedstorage

I have a Windows application that makes SQL connections to get some data. These data files are small and stored in .csv files in isolated storage, so that if the live Connection fails, the application warns the user that it is in offline mode and references the local files instead. Every time the user opens the application and connection is available, the .csv files are updated in the background.

The tester has come back to me because if, on the first time the user accesses the application, there is not SQL connection then the .csv files will not exist in isolated storage yet and errors are returned. I would therefore like to put some .csv files in the isolated storage as part of the Setup Project that creates the .msi that is used to install the application.

The Isolated storage doesn't appear in the list of special folders for the Setup Project...

[image: Available Special Folder Types in Setup Project]

How do I make it so that the files are created in isolated storage when the .msi file is executed?

Alternatively, do I need to add them to an assets folder and move them programmatically on the first use of the application? I am reluctant to do this as it seems inefficient and will make code that runs every time the application runs, but needs only to run once.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and .NET 4.8

Comment: Could you [create the files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-find-existing-files-and-directories-in-isolated-storage) on application launch instead? You can use "internal defaults" or copy content from template files installed elsewhere.

Comment: If that's the only way to do it, then yes - I could. I was hoping there was a way to avoid it, but if isolated storage just isn't built in to the setup projects, I guess it is probably the only option?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but I don't think it is built-in. Creating the files during the application launch from defaults or templates is arguably better though, for several reasons: **`1)`** Single source is better for maintenance and (unit) testing, **`2)`** Familiar development platform: easier to code, **debug** and maintain, **`3)`** Decouples file from deployment (setup does not ever touch them or "know" about them), **`4)`** Quality assurance teams can rig ad-hoc testing easily if the application can "recover" from unexpected settings on launch (very effective for some test scenarios).